# How to display a string with a regular size and filled with other characters than space using printf?

Tags: c, printf

I know that we can display a given string using `printf()` defining its minimum size. This can be done in this way, for example:

```
printf("%20s",str);
```

However, with this piece of code, *str* will be displayed with a minimum of 20 characters and, if the original string has less than 20 characters, the function completes with spaces at left.

Is there any way of doing this using other characters than white spaces?

Comment: There's no existing standard C functions to do it. But it's not hard to write a function which does it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes. I agree that it is not hard to implement this. I was just curious about the possibilities of printf.

Comment: `fwrite(str, 1, 20, stdout)`?

Comment: @Zaratruta, if your interest is specifically in the capabilities of `printf()`, then that function's documentation would be the most appropriate place to look.  You can find that in many places.  All will tell you that "If the converted value has fewer characters than the field width, it will be padded **with spaces** on the left or right" (emphasis added).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've already read it. However, I'm not sure if I was able to capture all the potential of the function. I'm asking here just for checking if someone else can figure out a way of doing what I want with printf that I was not able to do.

Comment: You could use `sprintf` and then change the buffer (e.g.) `sprintf(buf,"%20s","hello");` (or `sprintf(buf,"%-20s","hello");`) and then do: `for (int i = 0;  buf[i] != 0;  ++i) { if (buf[i] == ' ') buf[i] = '*'; } fputs(buf,stdout);` To me, that's the closest to straight `printf` to get what you want.

Comment: `printf` can use one of two padding characters: spaces by default, or for numbers with the `0` fag,  it pads with`0`'s.  For anything else, you're going to have to work outside of `printf`.  Me, I'd use `memset` to pre-fill a buffer with the padding character, then use `sprintf` to print the result into part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `printf` family has no ability to use arbitrary padding characters.

One possibility would be to use `memset` to pre-fill a buffer with the padding character, then use `sprintf` to print the result into part of it:

```
char *string = "Hello, world!";
int stringlen = strlen(string);
int fieldlen = 20;
char padchar = '#';

if(stringlen <= fieldlen) {
    char buf[fieldlen+1];
    memset(buf, padchar, fieldlen);
    sprintf(&buf[fieldlen - stringlen], "%s", string);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> if the original string has less than 20 characters, the function
> completes with spaces at left.
>
> Is there any way of doing this using other characters than white
> spaces?

**No,** not with `printf()` alone. The documentation (for example, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) specifically says that if the converted value has fewer characters than the field width, then the field is padded *with spaces* on the left or right, as appropriate.

The language spec is actually a little less clear on this point than many other sources:

> If the converted value has fewer characters than the field
> width, it is padded with spaces (by default) on the left (or right, if the left adjustment flag, described later, has been given) to the field width.

One might take the "by default" to indicate that another choice of padding character could somehow be specified, but careful reading of the specification does not reveal any such option.  The best interpretation, then, is that the "by default" is referring to the location of the padding (left), not the padding character.  Most other versions of the doc just leave out the "by default" bit, presumably because it is more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I might solve it like this

```
/* ... mystery content removed ... */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    printf("Left: " PAD_STAR_FMT "\n", PAD_STAR_ARG(argv[i], 20));

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    printf("Rite: " PADR_STAR_FMT "\n", PADR_STAR_ARG(argv[i], 20));

  return 0;
}
```

Run:

```
$ ./pad The quick brown fox "" "supercalifragilisticexpeali"
Left: *****************The
Left: ***************quick
Left: ***************brown
Left: *****************fox
Left: ********************
Left: supercalifragilistic
Rite: The*****************
Rite: quick***************
Rite: brown***************
Rite: fox*****************
Rite: ********************
Rite: supercalifragilistic
```

The `PAD_STAR_FMT` and `PADR_STAR_FMT` macros expands to a string literal which provides the conversion specifier for the star-padded print job.

The `PAD_STAR_ARG` and `PADR_STAR_ARG` macros expand to the argument to this conversion specifier.

As you can see, we encode the field width of 20 into the argument space rather than the format string because we need to be able to do some calculations with it, not possible in the format string language.

Under the hood, two conversion specifiers are used, and the `ARG` macros generate several arguments for them (unfortunately, with multiple evaluations of their own arguments).

The nice thing about this approach is that we can retrofit it into some existing code that already uses `printf` without otherwise disturbing that code. If the code makes a single `printf` call, we can keep it that way.

I recommend cleaning up the code and using better, perhaps shorter names. My if statements could be ternary operators, too.

The complete program follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

static char stars[] = {
  "**************************************************"
  "**************************************************"
  "**************************************************"
  "**************************************************"
  "**************************************************"
  "**************************************************"
  "**************************************************"
  "**************************************************"
  "**************************************************"
  "**************************************************"
};

#define PAD_STAR_FMT "%.*s%.*s"
#define PAD_STAR_ARG(S, N) pad_nstars(S, N), stars, pad_nchars(S, N), (S)

#define PADR_STAR_FMT "%.*s%.*s"
#define PADR_STAR_ARG(S, N) pad_nchars(S, N), (S), pad_nstars(S, N), stars

static int pad_nstars(const char *s, size_t width)
{
  assert (width < sizeof stars);
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  if (len > width)
    return 0;
  return (int) (width - len);
}

static int pad_nchars(const char *s, size_t width)
{
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  if (len > width)
    return width;
  return len;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("Left: " PAD_STAR_FMT "\n", PAD_STAR_ARG(argv[i], 20));
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("Rite: " PADR_STAR_FMT "\n", PADR_STAR_ARG(argv[i], 20));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any way of doing this using other characters than white spaces?

Yes, if that pad character is `'0'` and at least 1 needed.  Use arithmetic padding.

```
#define N 20
size_t len = strlen(str);
assert(len < N);
//       v------- Pad with 0
//       |v------ Obtain width from arguments
printf("%0*d%s",(int)(N-len), 0, str);
```

We can add code for alternate padding.  Good for `len` [0...N].

```
size_t len = strlen(str);
#define N 20
assert(len <= N);
char pad[N+1];
memset(pad, pad_char, N-len);
pad[len] = 0;
printf("%s%s",pad, str);
```